# how to get a float with desired precision using python

Tags: python

for example, i want to get a float with the initial 3 digits from e (2.71 from 2.718281828...), is there any function i can use ? i have tried round(), math.floor() and Decimal(1).exp() with getcontext().prec=1, but none of them gives me what i want (round() gives me 2.72, math.floor() 2 and Decimal(1).exp also 2.72) i dont want to round up the float.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
round(x - 0.005, 2)
# => 2.71
math.floor(x * 100) / 100
# => 2.71
```

Comment: Note: Like all of the solutions provided, this is working in terms of number of decimal places, not number of digits. Possible that works for the OP, but it's worth noting.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_DOWN
>>> from math import e
>>> print Decimal(e).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
2.71
```

Answer (score 1):

You can format a string with one extra digit, remove it, then cast back to `float`:

```
>>> float('{:.3f}'.format(2.718)[:-1])
2.71
```

Comment: aka `len(str(bool(x))) == 4`

Comment: This is awesome.

Comment: this approach is nice, but it has a dangerous edge case like `2.7998`, it converts to 2.80, so the target digits must be fixed.